# uwsgi + pypy "no app loaded" Error

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, uwsgi, pypy

I was trying to deploy website with uwsgi + pypy + flask. Failed with uwsgi error message as below:

```
*** no app loaded. GAME OVER ***
```

My Environment and scripts are:

```
$ uname -a
Linux xxxxx 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:12 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

$ pypy --version
Python 2.7.10 (3360adbeba4a, Apr 19 2016, 13:27:10)
[PyPy 5.1.0 with GCC 4.6.3]

$ uwsgi --version
1.9.17.1-debian

Note: the uwsgi is installed with pip in pypy virtualenv
```

flasktest.py:

```
from flask import Flask

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello!"
```

The command to run website

```
$ uwsgi --chmod-socket=777 \
--chdir /path/mysite --pypy-wsgi flasktest \
--master --socket 127.0.0.1:8000 --need-app
```

Anyone have any idea that in which part I did wrong?

Answer (score -2):

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/uwsgi/

> Please make sure in advance that any app.run() calls you might have in
>   your application file are inside an if **name** == '**main**': block
>   or moved to a separate file. Just make sure it’s not called because
>   this will always start a local WSGI server which we do not want if we
>   deploy that application to uWSGI.

**Starting your app with uwsgi**

uwsgi is designed to operate on WSGI callables found in python modules.

Given a flask application in myapp.py, use the following command:

```
$ uwsgi -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock --module myapp --callable app
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
$ uwsgi -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock -w myapp:app
```

The example:

```
from flask import Flask
application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but still not working. Since I am using pypy, the argument '-w' you mean '--pypy-wsgi', isn't it?